# New to PowerShell, trying to find something that gives this output for a list of IPs

Tags: powershell, server, ip, new-operator, ping

Like the title says i'm super new in PowerShell and i was trying to get the ping to a list of different IP's and servers at work.

I found this script on here and it kinda gives what i want (i touched a little bit):

```
$group = @()
    foreach ($ip in $Iplist) {
    $status = @{ "Servidor" = $ip; "Fecha" = (Get-Date -Format "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm") }
$pings = Test-Connection $ip
    if ($pings) {
        $status["AverageResponseTime"] =
            ($pings | Measure-Object -Property ResponseTime -Average).Average
    $status["Estado"] = "OK"
}
    else {
        $status["Estado"] = "Down"
}

        New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $status -OutVariable serverStatus
        $group += $serverStatus

}
```

The output to this one is this:

```
Estado Fecha            AverageResponseTime Servidor
------ -----            ------------------- --------
OK     03/09/2021 22:58                5.25 IP 1
OK     03/09/2021 22:58               33.75 IP 2
OK     03/09/2021 22:58                 5.5 IP 3
```

But i wanted to get an output like this:

```
------   --------        -------------------    ---   ---  --------
IP1     03/09/2021 22:58                5.25    4ms   6ms      OK
IP2     03/09/2021 22:58               33.75    25ms  40ms     OK    
IP3     03/09/2021 22:58                 5.5    4ms   6ms      OK
```

And honestly i dont know how to get it like that. If anyone has any advice/line i'll greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Ordered Hash Tables

This is due to how PowerShell doesn't enforce ordering of keys for hash-tables. More information here: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/use-powershell-to-create-ordered-dictionary/

To amend your code such that it will enforce the order, change this line, adding the `ordered` attribute tag:

```
$status = [ordered]@{ "Servidor" = $ip; "Fecha" = (Get-Date -Format "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm") }
```

This means your keys will be in the order you specify. When new keys are added they are kept at the end of the hashtable. Your final keys before creating the output object will be:

1. Servidor
2. Fecha
3. AverageResponseTime
4. Estado

Which I think is what you want.

### Select-Object

Another way of enforcing an order, just for display purposes is the `Select-Object` cmdlet. For example in your case, you can print the data in the order of choice by listing named Properties in order:

```
$group | Select-Object Servidor, Fecha, AverageResponseTime, Estado
```

Piping again to something like `Export-Csv` would create an output file with keys in the order specified.

Comment: Nice, but re terminology: syntactically, `[ordered]` is a _cast_, using a made-up _type literal_. It is purely - awkward - syntactic sugar, analogous to `[pscustomobject] @{ ... }` (which also isn't a real cast), though in the latter case at least the type exists as such.